# How to return a variable from an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn async functions and am struggling to get the following to work.

```js
async get_price(ticker) {
  var price = await axios
    .get(`https://marketwebsite.com/${ticker}`, {
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36",
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
      $(".todays_price").each((index, element) => {
        var value = $(element)
          .find(".current_price")
          .text()
          .replace(/\s\s+/g, "");
        return value;
        console.log(value); // THIS WORKS
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

When i call

```js
var price = get_price(symbol);
```

I cannot get any return from this function. The console log noted above does work, however i cannot get the value to return from this function.

I have tried to `await get_price(symbol)` as well.

Comment: You don't have a `return price` in `get_price()`;

Comment: maybe it doesn't return `price` because you didn't write `return price`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your snippet including:

- You are not returning price from your `get_price` function
- You are not returning anything in your `.then()` call

Try the following snippet:

```js
async function get_price(ticker) {
  return await axios
    .get(`https://marketwebsite.com/${ticker}`)
    .then((res) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
      return $(".todays_price").map((index, element) => {
        var value = $(element)
          .find(".current_price")
          .text()
          .replace(/\s\s+/g, "");
        return value;
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

get_price('ticker').then((res) => {
  console.log(res); // Should print array of the values
});
```

I've used the [jQuery .map](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method as it seems like you intended to return the values for each element.

I suggest going through the documentation on async await and promises on the MDN docs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: this is amazing, grateful for your help this works!

Answer (score 1):

there are two things:

first, the code in the `then()` block is returned to `price` variable that isn't returned

second, `var price = get_price(symbol);`  the function call is not using `await` so if you log that you will get the promise instead of the value.

you need to `return` the axios call and `await` it when using the function elsewhere